# Making a Get & a PUT call for an external rest service from inside a GET operation in Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

We have exposed a GET operation in the rest service using WebFlux.
Inside this GET operation if a call to the GET(or SET) operation of an external Rest service is made individually then everything works fine.
However if we try to merge these 2 calls within the same operation then the code fails, it doesnt make any calls to the backend service.
Sample code used inside a service operation called from the GET controller operation is  :

public void handleAddress(Map handleAddressRequest)
  {
      Tuple4> serviceConnectionDetails = commerceConnectorHelper
                .prepareDataForCheckOutCart(handleAddressRequest);

```
  serviceConnectionDetails._3
             .get() 
             .uri(CartRequestTranslator.getAddressDetailsEndPoint(serviceConnectionDetails._1, serviceConnectionDetails._2, serviceConnectionDetails._4.get(ServiceOperation.GET_USER_ADDRESSES))) 
             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
             .retrieve() 
             .bodyToMono(MonoAddressModel.class)
             .map(add -> add.getAddresses())
             .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).filter(defaultAddress -> defaultAddress.isDefaultAddress())
             .flatMap(obj -> {

                 System.out.println("Address default is "+obj.getId());

                 serviceConnectionDetails._3
                 .put()
                 .uri(CartRequestTranslator.putAddressDetailsEndPoint(serviceConnectionDetails._1, serviceConnectionDetails._2, serviceConnectionDetails._4.get(ServiceOperation.GET_USER_ADDRESSES), obj.getId()))
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                 .exchange()
                 .flatMap(test -> test.bodyToMono(String.class));

                 //returning a dummy flux object
                 return Flux.just("sdsdsd");
             });

   return ;
```

}

It would be great if any of you could share any inputs here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the reactor reference documentation, [nothing happens until you subscribe](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe).

In your code snippet, the Publisher returned by the put operation is not chained within the pipeline, so nothing will subscribe to it.

Greatly simplying your code snippet to clear the specifics, it should look a bit more like this:

```
Mono<Void> result = webClient
    .get().uri(uri).retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(MonoAddressModel.class)
    .map(model -> model.getAddress())
    .flatMap(address -> {
         return webClient.get().uri(address)
                    .exchange()
                    .then();
    });
```

In case a more complex setup (like your snippet) doesn't work, I'd suggest a couple of things:

- try regrouping operations in methods; it's easy to reason about small functions with explicit types for each step
- try adding `log()` operators in several places in your pipeline; maybe a filter operator is not well implemented and you're actually filtering all values.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the response. The put operation in this case has no values in the response but only the status code. In such a scenario what kind of subscription should be used. We tried with the onComplete and doOnStatus operations but that didnt helped. Also when we add this put call somehow the get call also stops working.  In our case we have around 8 rest calls from the same operation most of which are get and put followed by a final post call, if all these get put calls are successful. What should be the ideal reactive design for auch a scenario .Manish

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `Mono<Void>` and not even consider the response body in the second stage.